# Is there any benefit to deleting a reference to a large Python object before overwriting that reference?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I am running some memory-heavy scripts which iterate over documents in a database, and due to memory constraints on the server I manually delete references to the large object at the conclusion of each iteration:

```py
for document in database:
    initial_function_calls()

    big_object = memory_heavy_operation(document)
    save_to_file(big_object)

    del big_object

    additional_function_calls()
```

The `initial_function_calls()` and `additional_function_calls()` are each slightly memory-heavy. Do I see any benefit by explicitly deleting the reference to the large object for garbage collection? Alternatively, does leaving it and having it point to a new object in the next iteration suffice?

Comment: I'm putting my money on "it depends" ie that's probably an implementation detail. It depends on how the GC is implemented, but I'd go with "no, it makes no difference" for CPython. Since the GC implements a reference counting, both `del big_object` and `big_object = 1` will lower the reference count by one. It is not guaranteed when exactly the GC executes anyway.

Comment: I don't see it serving much of a purpose unless you're running out of space for `additional_function_calls()`. If `additional_function_calls()` needs to use the space that `big_object` otherwise would have, then there is a point to this, not otherwise

Comment: @inspectorG4dget correct me if I'm wrong, but it is not guaranteed that the GC will execute the second that the reference count for `big_object` hits 0. It may execute a bit later which will render `del big_object` non-effective in the very short run.

Comment: Note that, if you're having memory problems because of this, [you can invoke the garbage collector manually](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html)

Comment: Anyway you could force garbage collection via [`gc.collect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect).

Comment: What happens when the next iteration hits `big_object = memory_heavy_operation(document)`? Is the garbage collection done immediately once the reference is over-written?

Comment: @DeepSpace: `non-effective in the very short run` <- you're absolutely right. However, if you run out of memory entirely, then the GC will (hopefuly) be triggered. That's why I brought up the whole thing about `additional_function_calls` having space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As often in these cases; it depends. :-/

I'm assuming we're talking about CPython here.

Using `del` or re-assigning a name reduces the reference count for an object. Only if that reference could reaches 0 can it be de-allocated. So if you inadvertently stashed a reference to `big_object` away somewhere, using `del` won't help.

When garbage collection is triggered depends on the amount of allocations and de-allocations. See the documentation for [`gc.set_threshold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.set_threshold).

If you're pretty sure that there are no further references, you could use [`gc.collect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect) to *force* a garbage collection run. That might help if your code doesn't do a lot of other allocations.

One thing to keep in mind is that if the `big_object` is created by a `C` extension module (like e.g. `numpy`), it could manage its own memory. In that case the garbage collection won't affect it! Also small integers and small strings are pre-allocated and won't be garbage collected. You can use [`gc.is_tracked()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.is_tracked) to check if an object is managed by the garbage collector.

What I would suggest is that you run your program with and without `del`+`gc.collect()`, and monitor the amount of RAM used. On UNIX-like systems, look at the *resident set size*. You could also use [`sys._debugmallocstats()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._debugmallocstats).

Unless you see the resident set size grow and grow, I wouldn't worry about it.